# Get previous page url and save as pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf-generation

If I have a link test.dk/drill/1 and I on that page have a link, thats maybe link to a PHP page.

How can I then get the page with its @media print css, and save it to pdf, is there a PHP script that can do that, i know i can get the previous page with

> $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

But do someone know a php script that can take that URL/info and save the page to pdf in php, where it's using the/my @media pring css file ?

(I know there is plenty of tools to do this, but hope that someone can show an ex. on this, im new to php, so hope someone can help)

Comment: Try using [https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) - which uses the WebKit engine to render the HTML page. Perhaps this is what you want.

Comment: Hi Ohgodwhy, I have looked at that and im sorry to say it, but im new to some of these things, so can someone help with an ex. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of tools to do that, just Google for html to pdf converter

one of them:

https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Comment: Yes there are plenty of tools and im new to this so im quite confused, thats why im asking here.. and hope someone can come with an ex. that easy to setup and thats work. :-)